# Meteor.wrapAsync returning undefined inside Velocity Test

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, meteor-velocity

I am trying to unit test a method in my Meteor app. My simple method looks like this:

```
function hello(arg, cb) {
  console.log('-=> arg: ' + arg);
  seTimeout(function() {
    cb(null, 'hello! ' + arg);
   }, 3000);
}
```

And my test is

```
it('should say hello', function () {
  var syncHello = Meteor.wrapAsync(hello);
  console.log(JSON.stringify('-=> async hello: ' + hello));
  console.log(JSON.stringify('-=> sync hello: ' + syncHello));
  var resp = syncHello('joe');
  expect(resp).toEqual('hello! joe')
})
```

But when I run my test, it is failing because `syncHello is undefined`.
It will be very helpful if I know the reason why `Meteor.wrapAsync` is returning undefined when I am unit-testing and help me to run this function synchronously.

Comment: Your hello function is not asynchronous.  So it doesn't make sense to use wrapAsync here.  To make it async, wrap cb(null, "hello..") in a meteor setTimeout

Comment: @bluebird tried as recommended still returning undefined